# Add different table in one email

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, outlook

I have a system that automatically invoke an email. 
What I want to do is when the system trap that today is FRIDAY I want to create a 
different tables in one email.

As of now my system can invoke an email per day.

Here is what I want to achieve.

Example today is Monday The system will send :

*"List of expiry product for Tuesday Table" (Same with tuesday to thursday)*

*Tuesday - "List of expiry product for Wednesday"*

*Wednesday -  "List of expiry product for Thursday"*

*Thursday - "List of expiry product for Friday"*

and if the day is FRIDAY I want to email the list of expiry products for 3days Like this :

Below is the list of products that will expire on Saturday to Monday.
(Each day comes with different table in one email only) Like this :

*Below is the list of expiry product for[image: table] .*

As of now my system can send email per day. I don't know how I might going to achieve
the output for friday email blast.

**Here is what I have so far :**

I have created two different sub class. My one subclass is an email setup for Monday to Thursday
and the other one is an email setup for Friday which compose of 3days different tables.

```
Sub EmailMondayThursday

Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim c As New SqlConnection("myconnectionhere")
    Dim emaildate As String
emaildate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).Date.ToString("D")
    cmd.Connection = c
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_progspot_monitor"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prdname", "%")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prdcde", "%")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prdfrdate", Date.Today.AddDays(1))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prdtodate", Date.Today.AddDays(1))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", "%")
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    adp.SelectCommand = cmd
    adp.Fill(ds)

Dim dv As New DataView(ds.Tables(0))
    Dim dvfilter As DataTable = dv.ToTable(True, {"teledte"})
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable
    For Each dtrow As DataRow In dvfilter.Rows
        dv.RowFilter = "Total_Load < Potential_Load"
        dt2 = dv.ToTable(False, {"Date", "Prouduct Name", "Product Code",  "Total Sales"})
    Next

Dim builder As New StringBuilder
builder.Append("<!DOCTYPE html><html>")
builder.Append("<head></head>") 
builder.Append("<table>")   
builder.Append("<tr>")
builder.Append("<th>Date</th>")
builder.Append("<th>Product Name</th>")
    builder.Append("<th>Product Code</th>")
    builder.Append("<th>Total Sales</th>")
builder.Append("<tr>")  
builder.Append("</table>")  
builder.Append("</html>")
 For Each row As DataRow In dt2.Rows
        builder.Append("<tr>")
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 1
        For Each col As DataColumn In dt2.Columns
            builder.Append("<td class=""" & i & """>" & row(col).ToString + " " & "</td>")
            i = i + 1
        Next
        builder.Append("</tr>")
        builder.AppendLine()
    Next
builder.Append("</tbody>")
    builder.Append("</table>")
setemail("myemail@yahoo.com", "pass", builder.ToString)
```

End SUb

**And here is my Sub class for FridayEmail**

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim c As New SqlConnection("myconnectionhere")
        Dim emaildtefrm As String
    dim emaildteto as String
    emaildtefrm = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).Date.ToString("D")
    emaildteto = DateTime.Today.AddDays(3).Date.ToString("D")        
    cmd.Connection = c
        cmd.CommandText = "sp_progspot_monitor"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prdname", "%")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prdcde", "%")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prdfrdate", Date.Today.AddDays(1))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prdtodate", Date.Today.AddDays(3))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", "%")
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd
        adp.Fill(ds)

    Dim dv As New DataView(ds.Tables(0))
        Dim dvfilter As DataTable = dv.ToTable(True, {"teledte"})
        Dim dt2 As New DataTable
        For Each dtrow As DataRow In dvfilter.Rows
            dv.RowFilter = "Total_Load < Potential_Load"
            dt2 = dv.ToTable(False, {"Date", "Prouduct Name", "Product Code",  "Total Sales"})
        Next

    Dim builder As New StringBuilder
    builder.Append("<!DOCTYPE html><html>")
    builder.Append("<head></head>") 
    builder.Append("<body>")
    builder.Append("<p> Below is the list of expiry product from " & emaildtefrm & "to" & emaildteto &  "</p>")
    builder.Append("<table>")   
    builder.Append("<tr>")
    builder.Append("<th>Date</th>")
    builder.Append("<th>Product Name</th>")
        builder.Append("<th>Product Code</th>")
        builder.Append("<th>Total Sales</th>")
    builder.Append("<tr>")  
    builder.Append("</table>")  
    builder.Append("</html>")
     For Each row As DataRow In dt2.Rows
            builder.Append("<tr>")
            Dim i As Integer
            i = 1
            For Each col As DataColumn In dt2.Columns
                builder.Append("<td class=""" & i & """>" & row(col).ToString + " " & "</td>")
                i = i + 1
            Next
            builder.Append("</tr>")
            builder.AppendLine()
        Next
    builder.Append("</tbody>")
        builder.Append("</table>")
    setemail("myemail@yahoo.com", "pass", builder.ToString)
```

This code is for trapping the day today so that when the system know the day it will conditionally send an email based to the condition.

Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton1.Click

```
    Dim daytoday As String = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek

    If daytoday.ToString = "1" or Then
        EmailMondayThursday()
    ElseIf daytoday.ToString = "4" Then
        MsgBox("Thursday")

    ElseIf daytoday .ToString = "5" Then
    ProgSpotEmailFriday()
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem with the Subclass FridayEmail the output is like this:
[image]

What i want to achieve is something like below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your output for Friday is included in a single data table and you iterate over it which is why you have it as a single table.
You need to either have 3 tables, one for each day, or have it as single data table but group the products by the date in order to have 3 groups, then instead of iterating over the data table rows and appending HTML Row to the HTML, make this code inside another for loop that iterate over the groups, and inside the for loop create an HTML table, so the code should be like this, I don't know VB< so i added it as psudo code

Dim dv As New DataView(ds.Tables(0))
        Dim dvfilter As DataTable = dv.ToTable(True, {"teledte"})
        Dim dt2 As New DataTable
        For Each dtrow As DataRow In dvfilter.Rows
            dv.RowFilter = "Total_Load < Potential_Load"
            dt2 = dv.ToTable(False, {"Date", "Prouduct Name", "Product Code",  "Total Sales"})
        Next

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder
builder.Append("<!DOCTYPE html><html>")
builder.Append("<head></head>") 
builder.Append("<body>")
builder.Append("<p> Below is the list of expiry product from " & emaildtefrm & "to" & emaildteto &  "</p>")

For Each from emaildtefrm  to emaildteto 

builder.Append("<table>")   
builder.Append("<tr>")
builder.Append("<th>Date</th>")
builder.Append("<th>Product Name</th>")
    builder.Append("<th>Product Code</th>")
    builder.Append("<th>Total Sales</th>")
builder.Append("<tr>")  
builder.Append("</table>")  
builder.Append("</html>")
dim dayProducts as DataTable  = dt2.Select(get only products for this day)
 For Each row As DataRow In dayProducts .Rows
        builder.Append("<tr>")
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 1
        For Each col As DataColumn In dt2.Columns
            builder.Append("<td class=""" & i & """>" & row(col).ToString + " " & "</td>")
            i = i + 1
        Next
        builder.Append("</tr>")
        builder.AppendLine()
        Next
       builder.Append("</tbody>")
       builder.Append("</table>")
 Next
 builder.Append("</body>")


setemail("myemail@yahoo.com", "pass", builder.ToString)
```

Comment: Sorry but your answer is full of errors. Also I don't get it. I am sorry. Still I will try the logic you gave. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is why i mentioend that I don't know VB, but the idea is to draw 3 tables instead of one, so after you get the data table for the products, divide them into 3 tables, and build one HTML table for each one and append it to the final email body

Comment: Yah that's what I'm trying to do before posting my question. Still confuse one how I might achieve that kind of output. I really don't know where to start :(